# Generics with inheritance design - need help to fix

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am having problem with my design:

I have some base class

```
public class ReportConfig<T> where T: class
{
    public string ReportSavePath { get; set; }
    public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
    public T ReportData { get; set; }
}
```

and this class can be extended into (one of possible subclass presented):

```
public class CsvReportConfig<T> : ReportConfig<T> where T : class
{
     // some extra class specific props
}
```

Then, I have a ReportGenerator abstract class

```
public abstract class ReportGenerator<T> where T : ReportConfig<T>
{
    public ReportGenerator(ReportConfig<T> config)
    {
        Config = config;
    }

    public ReportConfig<T> Config { get; set; }
    public abstract ReportGenerationResult GenerateReport();
}
```

and then, I would like to extend the `ReportGenerator` class into:

```
public class Csv1ReportGenerator : ReportGenerator<CsvReportConfig<DataObj>>
{
    public Csv1ReportGenerator (CsvReportConfig<DataObj> config) : base(config)
    {

    }

    public override ReportGenerationResult GenerateReport()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here, I am receiving an error that

> `CsvReportConfig<DataObj>` cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in
>   generic type or method `ReportGenerator<T>`.

What am I doing wrong and how to correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to do

```
public class ReportGenerationResult { }
public class DataObj { }
public class ReportConfig<T> where T : class
{
    public string ReportSavePath { get; set; }
    public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
    public T ReportData { get; set; }
}

public class CsvReportConfig<T> : ReportConfig<T> where T : class
{}

public abstract class ReportGenerator<T,U> where T : ReportConfig<U> where U : class
{
    protected ReportGenerator(T config)
    {
        Config = config;
    }

    public T Config { get; set; }
    public abstract ReportGenerationResult GenerateReport();
}
public class Csv1ReportGenerator : ReportGenerator<CsvReportConfig<DataObj>, DataObj>
{
    public Csv1ReportGenerator(CsvReportConfig<DataObj> config) : base(config)
    {
    }

    public override ReportGenerationResult GenerateReport()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

## Edit

These are the main changes that were made.

- `ReportGenerator` - This was the main change. It looks like you want to specify a generic type parameter for the property `Config` (*constrained to types that are or extend `ReportConfig<T>`*) in any implementations. To do this and to keep the `ReportConfig.ReportData` generic you have to use 2 generic type parameters where the second type parameter is reused to constrain `ReportConfig<T>`.
- `Csv1ReportGenerator` - now when this inherits `ReportGenerator<CsvReportConfig<DataObj>, DataObj>` instead of `ReportGenerator<CsvReportConfig<DataObj>>` which now enables this type to have property `Config` which would be constrained to type `CsvReportConfig<DataObj>` which is what you were trying to do.

Comment: Yes, exactly I figured it out - this is the right answer. Thanks

Comment: could you explain, what was wrong with OP's code, and why your solution actually solves it?

Comment: I was missing some generics constraints

Comment: @pitersmx not really, you were using `T` in the inheritance of `ReportGenerator` to specify the wrong generic element in `ReportConfig<T>`. But elaborating on this would really improve the quality of the answer

Comment: @MongZhu - I had some time and added an explanation below. Feel free to edit if you want.